# Firebase user counter

Tags: firebase, shopify

I'm trying to display the amount of users that are currently viewing my page using firebase and shopify's API. Haven't been able to find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a presence system - see this Firebase [blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-06-17-howto-build-a-presence-system.html).

When a user logs in,

1. Authenticate the user
2. Set the [`onDisconnect`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/ondisconnect/index.html) listener to remove the presence object (#3) when the user disconnects.
3. Set the user's presence ref to `true`

#### Example (from blog post)

```js
var amOnline = new Firebase('https://<demo>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected');
var userRef = new Firebase('https://<demo>.firebaseio.com/presence/' + userid);
amOnline.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    userRef.onDisconnect().remove();
    userRef.set(true);
  }
});
```